# Failure to start in frigid temperatures

Tags: ford, starting, fuel-pump

RE 2001 Ford Explorer 
It has a new battery, coil, and wires in place. The truck will not start below -7 F despite strong cranking; in these temperatures, sound of fuel pump priming is muted or absent.  Upon rewarming, the truck starts briskly and pump sounds return.  No other classic signs of fuel pump failure.  Any ideas that you may have would be hugely appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: The fuel pump is inside the fuel tank. Is the fuel level gauge working properly?

Comment: Check the operation of the fuel pump relay. I would suspect that something electrical is failing to send power to the pump as opposed to the pump itself.

Comment: Did you check the voltage to the pump while it's priming?

Answer (score 1):

I have experience on similar situation. It was -20 degree Celsius and engine was choked on my case.

As people indicated your problem could be the fuel pump. Trapped water (ice)  inside the gas tank can cause failure of the pump. You may need to check if fuel pressure is ok on the engine side.

This may help.
[Fiat Punto Wont Start. Fuel Light & Three warning lights flashing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24137/fiat-punto-wont-start-fuel-light-three-warning-lights-flashing/25628#25628)